# Tighten the kerning for a particular pair?

Tags: css, fonts, kerning

I need to use the Palatino font in a website. The problem is that the font is missing an important kerning pair VA, at least on my machine:

[image: Kerning sample]

It’s acceptable for me to just solve this situation in the main website heading. This means I can insert explicit markup (`<span class="kern">VA</span>LUE`) and adjust the kerning there. But adjusting the VA pair using the `letter-spacing` CSS property also tightens the following pair:

[image: Kerning sample after tightening]

Now the AL pair is unacceptable (also see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Msdwm/1/)). What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created this project for exactly this purpose:

> [Jerning.com](http://jerning.com)

Usage is simple - so for your example you would do the following:

```
$('p').jerning("VA", -0.1);
```

Which means you don't have to do manual editing of spans for large bodies of text.

Comment: Ha! Very nice, thank you. Better than marking up my pairs by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Ha, I’m an idiot. Obviously, just target the first letter:

```
<p>VALUE</p>
<p><span class="kern">V</span>ALUE</p>
```

So much for rubber duck debugging.